# What are the similarities between Zellig Harris' work and Chomsky's early work of Generative grammars?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, philosophy-of-language

Since my knowledge of Chomsky's work is limited to context free grammars I am particularly interested in the relation of Zellig's work to Chomsky's conception of abstract syntax trees and automata theory in languages.

Comment: Similarities of a [legacy?](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~jagoldsm/Papers/ZelligHarris.pdf):"*Today, I daresay Harris is remembered by most linguists as the mentor and advisor to Noam Chomsky at the University of Pennsylvania — and the originator of transformational analysis*". For more details see Nevin's chapter [Noam and Zellig](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268872757_Noam_and_Zellig).

Comment: The chapter that you cited is great and provides more than what I needed. I didn't know some of the darker aspects of Chomsky's personality.I knew Chomsky primarily from some of his debates with people that were clearly inferior to him IQ-wise so he didn't (and didn't need to) show any doubious behavior in order to win the debates with them.